# how to do a custom callback on a user function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I use callbacks all the time when using 3rd part libraries such as jquery, however I've run into an issue where I need to set up my own call back. Take for instance my current code:

```
// Get All Rates
function getAllRates() {
    $('#shiplist tr.mainRow').each(function() {

        var curid = $(this).attr("id");
        var cursplit = curid.split("_");
        var shipid = cursplit[1];

        getRate(shipid);

    });

}
```

This iterates through all the table rows that have class "mainRow", and each main row has the id of "shipment_#####" so for each row it splits by the _ to get the actual ship id, which it then uses to calla  "getRate" function which sends an ajax call to the server using UPS or USPS api's to get the rate for the given shipment.

This works fine for UPS all rows start loading at once and return their rates independently. The problem is now with Stamps.com, they use an authenticated soap conversation so an authenticator string needs to be received from the first call and used in the next call and so on.

So basically I need to modify the above function to execute the "getRate()" function and wait for it to complete before executing the next iteration.

Anyone know how I can do this with out a lot of fuss?

EDIT - Clearification on the question being asked:

I want to take the following function:

getRate(shipid);

and access it like so:

getRate(shipid, function(shipList) { _Function_data_here_ });

When I define the getRate function, how do I define it so that it has that callback ability? how does that work?

Comment: Your above each loop should wait for getRate to complete before iterating already. What you might want to do for Stamps.com is have getRate return the authenticator string which you could store in a variable and send during the next iteration

Comment: All things aside, you need to look at [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`$.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (but not [`$.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which is deprecated and very inefficient).

Comment: My system already does the authenticator hand off but the problem is multiple are being executed at the same time. I need to know how to "wait" or call back with the next iteration. I would prefer not to use synchronous ajax but i guess i will if i have to.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not exactly sure how .on and .delegate apply to this scenario since this is not "event" based. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: So there is no event on `getRate()`? You would probably be better off with Felix Kling's answer. Otherwise, you could add a custom event handler to call when `getRate()` finishes.

Comment: ^^^ This is what i wanted to know how to do initially, I wanted to know how to set up an "finished" event for that function as a 'callback' to run the next iteration. No worries though, I figured out a different way and I'm sure one day I'll have to learn this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you extract all the IDs at once and pass them to your function. That way, you can easily process the first on individually and the rest afterwards. With deferred objects, this is really easy.

For example:

```
function extractAllIds(callback) {

    var ids = $('#shiplist tr.mainRow').map(function() {
        return this.id.split('_')[1];
    }).get();

    callback(ids);
}

function getRates(ids) {
    var first = ids.shift();

    $.ajax({data: first, ...}).done(function(response) {
        // extract the authenticator string
        for(var i = ids.length; i--; ) {
            $.ajax({data: ids[i], ...});
        }
    });
}

extractAllIds(getRates);
```

In any way, you cannot make `$.each` wait for response of Ajax calls.

Comment: I will try this, or something similar to this.

Comment: I wonder if [`$.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) makes sense here? Does `deferred.done()` count as a `promise`?

Comment: @Jared: The promise interface is a subset of the deferred interface, which only allows to add callbacks but not to resolve or reject it. I assume (but don't know for sure) that `$.ajax` already returns a promise object.

Comment: That was actually what I was thinking, just didn't know if it would work above a level like this. I've not used a `promise` explicitly, either, so I thought it worth asking.

Comment: This is cool, though it will get slightly more involved if you need to handle mixed lists (ie. UPS/USPS/Stamps accounts in the same table).

Comment: I selected this answer because it got me into the mode of thinking that allowed me to figure out a solution. As advised I got the list of shipments in order, each pushed onto an array, then I call the get rates function recursively, each time popping the last id off the array. Essentially the ajax complete/success function checks the length of the (global) array stack of shipments, if there is values it call the main function again after pop. Works like a charm!

Comment: @SublymeRick: I'm glad I was able to help :) FWIW, you can also provide your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: Either the question is poorly worded, or the above solution is incorrect. If EVERY call depends on the previous call, then the callback to getRates needs to be recursive, which in above case, isn't. The solution Felix Kling provides here is for the case when you only need to obtain an authenicator string once, not every time.